# Python attempt mongodb connection, if can't then pull local data

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

I'm working with a single board computer that can run python 2.7 scripts. In the "real world" this computer needs to be able to access a database to pull a pin number and user information.

If a connection to the database isn't possible, say because of an internet outage, the computer needs to be able to pull information from the local filesystem as a standard text or json file.

How can I program the script so that it first attempts to connect to the database, and if it can't it then pulls from a local text file.

Right now I just have

```
#connect to our database
connection = MongoClient(HOST, PORT)
db = connection[DATABASE]
if db.authenticate(USER, PASS):
    #Pull info from database
else:
    #Load info from text file
```

But after not being able to connect it still just throws me an error. I assume the answer is a try, except block. But is the answer really as simple as

```
#connect to our database
try:
    connection = MongoClient(HOST, PORT)
    db = connection[DATABASE]
    db.authenticate(USER, PASS):
    #Pull info from database
except:
    #Load info from text file
```

EDIT: The try and accept statement seems to work, but is there a way for it to recognize it can't connect faster? It seems to take about 20 to 30 seconds before it decides it can't connect. I'm want to make it so if it can't connect in about 10 seconds look towards the local filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question

I had to set a serverSelectionTimeoutMS variable when I originally established the connection, full code is as shown

```
#5 second timer
DB_TIMEOUT = 5000

try:
    connection = MongoClient(HOST, PORT, serverSelectionTimeoutMS=DB_TIMEOUT)
    db = connection[DATABASE]
    db.authenticate(USER, PASS)
    print("connected")
    #pull from database function
except:
    print("not connected")
    #pull from filesystem function
```

The script will attempt to connect to the database, if it can't withing 5 seconds it will pull from the local system